# Cannot share a post to Facebook using ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

We are trying to share something on facebook and we followed these steps
https://ionicframework.com/docs/enterprise/social-sharing but it doesnt work.

```
constructor(navParams: NavParams,
 public modalCtrl: ModalController,
 public navCtrl: NavController,
 private social : SocialSharing
    )
```

The problem is that if this  `private social : SocialSharing` is present, an app stops working with this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at index.js:411
    at Module../node_modules/@ionic-native/social-sharing/__ivy_ngcc__/index.js (index.js:594)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../src/app/card-fullscreen/card-fullscreen.page.ts (card-fullscreen.page.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.module.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:12)
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you try this in web browser?

Comment: Yes, we have been testing this on localhost compiler and tested in web browser. I think that issue is not here. Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Did you try in mobile or emulator?